# Rust if let =, seems to leak the RHS function result on Ubuntu Linux, is this expected?

Tags: rust, scope

I have the following code, which runs fine on Mac and Windows, but panics on Ubuntu Linux. The panic is at the `borrow_mut` and the indication is that `server` is already immutably borrowed. That would seem to indicate that the `if` leaked the `server` borrow, which I wasn't expecting it to do. I then wrapped the 3 `if`s within a `{ }` and Ubuntu Linux no longer panics. Which I think proves that the `if` leaked the borrow. Am I wrong? is this expected? Or, is there something else going on with Rust and `AtomicRefCell` that I'm unaware of?

`AtomicRefCell` comes from [atomic_refcell](https://crates.io/crates/atomic_refcell).

```
static server: AtomicRefCell<Server> = AtomicRefCell::new(Server {..});
...
if let ServerField::Executor(executor) = &server.borrow().executor {
    executor.stop();
}
if let ServerField::Scheduler(scheduler) = &server.borrow().scheduler {
    scheduler.stop()
}
if let ServerField::Monitor(monitor) = &server.borrow().monitor {
    monitor.stop()
}
let mut s = server.borrow_mut();
...
```

Here's the code that works with all 3 platforms:

```
// ensure that server.borrows don't leak out.
{
    if let ServerField::Executor(executor) = &server.borrow().executor {
        executor.stop();
    }
    if let ServerField::Scheduler(scheduler) = &server.borrow().scheduler {
        scheduler.stop()
    }
    if let ServerField::Monitor(monitor) = &server.borrow().monitor {
        monitor.stop()
    }
}
let mut s = server.borrow_mut();
...
```

Here is a complete impl to illustrate the problem. `main.rs`:

```
use atomic_refcell::AtomicRefCell;

#[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
static server: AtomicRefCell<Server> = AtomicRefCell::new(Server {
    value: ServerField::Uninitialized,
});

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Server {
    value: ServerField,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ServerField {
    Uninitialized,
    Value(usize),
}

fn start() {
    server.borrow_mut().value = ServerField::Value(41);
}

fn stop() {
    // enclose this in a scope to not panic
    let borrow = &server.borrow();
    println!("value is {:#?}", borrow.value);
    drop(borrow);
    // end scope
    let mut s = server.borrow_mut();
    s.value = ServerField::Uninitialized;
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    start();
    stop();
}
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test() {
        start();
        stop();
    }
}
```

Add this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
atomic_refcell = "0.1"
```

In this example an `if let` is employed with a RHS of &server.borrow().value, which doesn't panic on Mac but may panic on Ubuntu Linux (I don't have a Linux box, and didn't upload to `GitHub` and create a workflow). However, this mirrors my code that I do have on `GitHub` with a workflow, where it showed that behavior.

```
use atomic_refcell::AtomicRefCell;

#[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
static server: AtomicRefCell<Server> = AtomicRefCell::new(Server {
    value: ServerField::Uninitialized,
});

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Server {
    value: ServerField,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ServerField {
    Uninitialized,
    Value(usize),
}

fn start() {
    server.borrow_mut().value = ServerField::Value(41);
}

fn stop() {
    if let ServerField::Value(val) = &server.borrow().value {
        println!("value is {:#?}", val);
    }
    let mut s = server.borrow_mut();
    s.value = ServerField::Uninitialized;
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    start();
    stop();
}
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_start_stop() {
        start();
        stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really difficult to determine what could be causing the issue without more context. Which crate is providing the `AtomicRefCell` type? Are you sure that the same code paths are being executed on each platform?

Comment: added AtomicRefCell info and link. I'm pretty sure all three ran the same codepath, as the change I made was the only change and it "fixed" Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a fix for the underlying issue, but could you try borrowing the server first and then using the same borrow in each if statement? e.g. `let s = server.borrow(); if let ServerField::Executor(...) = ... { ... }; drop(s); let mut s = server.borrow_mut();`

Comment: sure, but other than performance, I don't expect it to be any different than the scope I created by wrapping the ifs in a {}. However, it does raise a question. Did the compiler do some optimizing, recognizing the same borrow and code-lift it out, forgetting to add the drop.

Comment: Well, that was unexpected. It did the panic. I had to wrap the borrow and drop in a scope to prevent it. That would seem to indicate that drop(borrow) is delaying the drop whereas it doesn't delay it when exiting a scope.

Comment: Can you create a [mre] that demonstrates the problem? I mocked up something to plug into Compiler Explorer but the LLVM IR and assembly is the same whether or not you add the extra scope, which suggests my mockup does not suffer from the same problem. At least, if you can show a minimal example that demonstrates the problem we could narrow down whether the problem is in your program, rustc, LLVM, or the OS.

Comment: Sure, give me 30 min, better make that an hour in case I have trouble reproducing. I'll extend my original with the demo.

Comment: well, that wasn't too bad. I stayed close to my original, as it might be something odd about how I'm using with enums and fields.

Comment: Interestingly, if I comment out the let .. borrow() and the drop(borrow) and change the println!("{}",&server.borrow().value); it doesn't panic, at least on my mac, it still might on ubuntu-linux.

Comment: It may have something to do with the &server.borrow vs server.borrow. If I change to using that, then it doesn't panic.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded example. I still don't quite know what to make of this but I can clear up one thing. `let borrow = &server.borrow()` stores `server.borrow()` in a temporary that lasts until the end of the smallest enclosing scope, then takes a reference to the temporary and stores it in `borrow`. I think you're imagining that to be like `(&server).borrow()` but it's actually `&(server.borrow())`. So it's not surprising in the minimized example that adding a scope makes it not panic: that should be the behavior on all platforms.

Comment: With the `if let` of the original code, I'm not 100% sure how that's supposed to work, but I believe the "smallest enclosing scope" of the `if let` expression is just the `if let` itself. So my expectation there would be no panic, even without the extra `{}` block. Even if I'm wrong about that, though, it should panic consistently. Can you confirm whether the minimized example behaves differently on Windows or Mac than Linux? Or do all three platforms treat it the same?

Comment: Yes, it is odd, but when behind the if let it did not panic on Mac or Windows. I've since changed to the server.borrow() sans &, and use &borrow.field within the if let and that seems to work everywhere. It also explains why the scope "fixed" it.

Comment: I'll need to change to an if-let. Let me do that and test.